# Reorder WPF datagrid columns

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I would like to give to the user a settings where he can reorder the columns of a `datagrid`. I know i can use the `DisplayIndex` to achieve this but my problem is how can i save the order of each column, how can i know what column was moved to the first position and so on?

I thought in using the Column header for that but i don't know if that is the best solution.

below is the datagrid that im using:

```
<DataGrid GridLinesVisibility="All" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#FFE5E2DB" IsReadOnly="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DisplayIndexes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserSortColumns="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,0" Name="dgDisplayIndexes"  
                      TabIndex="1" RowHeight="30" 
                      CanUserAddRows="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ColumnWidth="Auto" CanUserReorderColumns="True" 
                      CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="150">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" DisplayIndex="0" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn SortMemberPath="status"  
                                        Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_STATUS.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                                        DisplayIndex="1" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Height="16" Width="16" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding status, Converter={StaticResource getIconForStatus}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="#" 
                    Binding="{Binding bonnummer}"  
                    DisplayIndex="2" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_NAAM.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding achternaam}" 
                    DisplayIndex="3" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_ADRES.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding Adres}" 
                    DisplayIndex="4" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_PC.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding Postcode}" 
                    DisplayIndex="5" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_PLAATS.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding plaats}" 
                    DisplayIndex="6"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_TELEFOON.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding telefoonnummer}" 
                    DisplayIndex="7" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_AANTALBESTELLINGEN.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding AantalBestellingen}" 
                    DisplayIndex="8" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_KAARTCOORDINATEN.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding Coordinaten}" 
                    DisplayIndex="9" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_GEBIED.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding bezorggebied}" 
                    DisplayIndex="10" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_KM.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding afstand, StringFormat='{}{0:N2}'}" 
                    DisplayIndex="11" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_REISTIJD.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding reistijd}" 
                    DisplayIndex="12" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_TIJD.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding tijd, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" 
                    DisplayIndex="13" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_OUD.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding oud}" 
                    DisplayIndex="14" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_BEZORGTIJD.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding gereed_om, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" 
                    DisplayIndex="15" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn     
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_BEZORGER.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding bezorger}" 
                    DisplayIndex="16" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_VERTROKKEN.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding bezorger_vertrokken_om, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" 
                    DisplayIndex="17" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_OVER.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding bezorgerterugover}" 
                    DisplayIndex="18" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_TERUG.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding bezorgerterug, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" 
                    DisplayIndex="19" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_KEUKEN.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding keuken}" 
                    DisplayIndex="20" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="{Binding Vertaling.DELIVERY_BEZORGORDER_LOPENDEORDERSTAB_DG_TELAATBERICHTUITOM.Vertaling, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
                    Binding="{Binding TeLaatBerichtTijd, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm}}" 
                    DisplayIndex="21" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can bind DataGrid's DisplayIndex property to property in your ViewModel:

```
...
<DataGridTextColumn 
                    Header="#" 
                    Binding="{Binding bonnummer}"  
                    DisplayIndex="{Binding BonnummerIndex, Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=2}" ... />
...
```

BonnummerIndex is your ViewModel property that stores column display position. You can also bind to array element ie. `DisplayIndex="{Binding ColumnsOrder[2], Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue=2}"`. FallbackValue is set to default column position. You need that to avoid DisplayIndex's default value (-1) which in turn throws out of range exception. TwoWay bindig is needed to reflect user changes back in ViewModel.

Later on you can serialize / de-serialize class to persists user settings.

You just need to be careful cause changing DisplayIndex of one column may change DisplayIndex(es) of other column(s).

Comment: Thank you for you reply, but that part i already knew how to do, Binding the displayIndex to a property on my viewmodel and setting the Fallback value to prevent exceptions. My question is more on the settings side, where i let the user change the position of the columns so when he loads the user control with that datagrid the columns will stay on the place he has set them in. My doubt is on how i will keep track of what column is on position 0 and what column is on position 2, for example. I hope you can understand now my question.

Comment: If you bind DisplayIndex to property on ViewModel, then bindings  will automatically update ViewMonel when user will re-sequence columns (drag and drop columns). To persist data you can serialize object which stores DisplayIndexes to disk and deserialize from disk  on application/control load.

Comment: Thank you, i has able to solve the problem by creating a new class and saving the index of each column, that im  later calling on the usercontrol with the datagrid in it.